# Android: Why the Runnable got nullpointerexception when refering the outer class method?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have met a strange case, here is my sample code.

```
public class MyMonitorService extends Service {
private MyMonitorManager mMyMonitorManager = new MyMonitorManager();
private Timer mTimer = new Timer();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public boolean isHome(){
    /**
     * Sample code
     */
    return true;
}

public void start(){
    mTimer.schedule(r, 1000);
}

private TimerTask r = new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(isHome()){
                // xxxxx
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

};
```

}

On some customized ROM/Phone, such as MIUI, though rarely, I got the nullpointerexception when execute `if(isHome())`, and the application crashes..

Even I changed the TimerTask to

```
    private TimerTask r = new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(mMyMonitorManager.isRunning()){
                // xxxxx
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

};
```

I still got the nullpointerexception when `if(mMyMonitorManager.isRunning())`..

I think sometimes the MyMonitorService.this is set by the dalvik, that's the only possible explanation for this because I already protect the whole run method with try-catch with any exception...Is it possible that the inner class lost its outer class reference?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Service is getting destroyed, and so the outer class is no longer available.

Since your Service is returning null from onBind, I assume you want to start your service using startService or an intent filter in your manifest. But do you have an onStartCommand method? That is where you are supposed to do the work of your service, and the return value from that function determines whether the service stays running.

Is your intent to keep the service running while your TimerTask is running, and then stop it? In that case, you could launch the TimerTask from within onStartCommand, return START_STICKY, and then stop the service when the TimerTask finishes. Something like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mTimer.schedule(r, 1000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private TimerTask r = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(isHome()){
                // xxxxx
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
};
```

This probably isn't good enough, because I'm guessing there could be more than one task going at once. You would need some way of knowing that all the tasks are complete before stopping the service. Even if you've called startService multiple times, the first call to stopService or stopSelf stops the service for all the calls.

Comment: yes, there is the onStartCommand. I didn't paste the method for simplicity. Actually it returns START_STICKY.   And talking of the problem, when the Service is destroyed, I think it only means its state more than the Java references or something....Is it?

Comment: It does seem like an outer-class reference should be enough to at least keep the Service object in memory, but maybe those are being treated specially. So if you have a sticky Service, how is it being stopped?